# add value (nunber) per same year from an array of objects

Tags: filter, array.prototype.map

`const db1 = [   { year: "2000", state: "Rio", month: "November", number: 18 },   { year: "2002", state: "Perambuco", month: "February", number: 64 },   { year: "2001", state: "Mato Grasso", month: "March", number: 112 },   { year: "2003", state: "Roraima", month: "January", number: 547 },   { year: "2002", state: "Maranhoo", month: "July", number: 4 },   { year: "2003", state: "Rio", month: "March", number: 9 },   { year: "2000", state: "Roraima", month: "October", number: 25 },   { year: "2001", state: "Paraiba", month: "January", number: 11 }, ];`

I have the following array of objects.  from db1 I want to filter out only the keys (year, number) and add the number (values) per same respective year ex:

`{ year: "2002", number: 68 },   { year: "2000", number: 43 },   { year: "2003", number: 556 },   { year: "2001", number: 123 },`

any feedback is appreciated.

`const sumArrayVals = (db1) => {    return db1.reduce((a, b) => {      Object.keys(b).map((c) => (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + b[c]));      return a;    }); };)`

Answer (score 0):

took a bit but got it.

```
const sumPerYear = db1.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  // increment or initialize to cur.number
  acc[cur.year] = acc[cur.year] + cur.number || cur.number;
  return acc;
}, {});
```